# How to change font on Magento 1.9 store

Tags: css, magento, fonts

I got Magento online store on localhost, there is set a Google font as a default.

I need to change the font, but the problem is, the new font is not a Google font.

Please note, I am an amateur, so please be VERY specific what should I do, what and where should I upload and replace.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do following steps.

1. Go to the admin and see what theme/template you are using for your store.
2. Then go to app/design/frontend
3. Locate your theme package
4. Then locate page.xml file. It should be under app/design/frontend/themackage/default/layout
   This xml file shall let you know about all the different css being used in your theme.
5. Identify your css file.
6. Then go to skin/front/your them package.

Here you will find your css file.

You can change the css element in your target file.

Answer (score 0):

You've got to search in the Magento shop's them main css and change the font used.

You can duplicate the current theme, update the font in the new one then install the new theme.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are using a custom font yes? That means you have a font file like a .woff or .eot.

In your styles.css or custom.css add:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: Myfontname;
    src: url(Myfontfile.woff);
}
```

Make sure that the url points to the font file. Add the font file in the same directory as the theme to use it as above.

After that, specify the elements you want to apply the font to. For example if you want all the headings to be this font:

```css
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5 {
  font-family: 'Yourfontname', sans-serif;
}
```

You can either use serif or sans serif (those are the little hooks on a font, see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serif)).

The process is similar to that of Wordpress, so [these instructions](https://www.hoasted.com/blog/change-wordpress-font-css/) work too.